# MySQL: Duplicate Rows When Inner Joining

Tags: mysql, duplicates, inner-join

I'm new in this website. I'm trying to find a solution about this duplicating row problem for my attendance system created in PHP and MySQL.

In this system, each user can perform check-ins and check-outs for each working day. Some users can perform multiple check-ins and check-outs in the single day for shift work, ignoring the LATE status (after 9.05am during check-in) and EARLY status (before 5.00pm during check-out).
There are three tables in the MySQL database for this system.

**tbl_checkin, which used to store check in data have these contents in the database:**

```
ID     User_Id     Date          Time     Late_status          Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     UGT001     2017-12-29     08:14:13                   No Comment
2     UGT002     2017-12-29     09:54:52     LATE          Comment Goes Here
3     UGT001     2017-12-30     09:16:34     LATE          Sending kids to school
4     UGT002     2017-12-30     08:21:04               
5     UGT003     2018-01-02     08:05:11                   
6     UGT003     2018-01-02     12:05:32                   Second Checkin
```

**tbl_checkout, which used to store check out data:**

```
ID     User_Id     Date          Time     Early_status          Comment
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     UGT001     2017-12-29     17:14:13                   
2     UGT002     2017-12-29     15:54:13     EARLY         Hospital Appointment
3     UGT001     2017-12-30     16:58:21     EARLY         Late for movie night
4     UGT002     2017-12-30     18:00:43               
5     UGT003     2018-01-02     10:30:44                   Break Time
6     UGT003     2018-01-02     18:04:45
```

**tbl_userlogin, which used to store user data (and other information not shown here such as work start date, end date, password, duration, role and user status):**

```
ID     User_Id     Name          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     UGT001     KEVIN MARTIN                 
2     UGT002     AHMAD BIN IBRAHIM  
3     UGT003     ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA
```

For this problem, I have used this SQL query to display a complete attendance log showing the user name, user ID, date, check in time, check out time, check in comment and check out comment, sorting the newest entry (by date) first:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    b.name AS Name, 
    c.user_id AS User_ID , 
    c.date AS Date, 
    a.time As "Time In",
    c.time As "Time Out",
    a.comment AS "Comment In",
    c.comment AS "Comment Out" 
FROM 
tbl_checkout c 
LEFT JOIN tbl_checkin a ON c.date=a.date AND c.user_id=a.user_id 
INNER JOIN tbl_userlogin b ON c.user_id=b.user_id 
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

Here is the result that should I supposed to display:

```
Name                    User_ID     Date         Time In     Time Out     Comment In               Comment Out
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    12:05:32     18:04:45    Second Checkin           
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    08:05:11     10:30:44                            Break Time
KEVIN MARTIN            UGT001    2017-12-30    09:16:34     16:58:21    Sending kids to school   Late for movie night
AHMAD BIN IBRAHIM       UGT002    2017-12-30    08:21:04     18:00:43
AHMAD BIN IBRAHIM       UGT002    2017-12-29    09:54:52     15:54:13    Comment Goes Here        Hospital Appointment
KEVIN MARTIN            UGT001    2017-12-29    08:14:13     17:14:13    No Comment
```

However, executing this SQL query will show like this instead:

```
Name                    User_ID     Date         Time In     Time Out     Comment In               Comment Out
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    12:05:32     10:30:44    Second Checkin           Break Time
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    08:05:11     18:04:45    
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    12:05:32     18:04:45    Second Checkin           
ALISYA PUTRI KARISMA    UGT003    2018-01-02    08:05:11     10:30:44                            Break Time
KEVIN MARTIN            UGT001    2017-12-30    09:16:34     16:58:21    Sending kids to school   Late for movie night
AHMAD BIN IBRAHIM       UGT002    2017-12-30    08:21:04     18:00:43
AHMAD BIN IBRAHIM       UGT002    2017-12-29    09:54:52     15:54:13    Comment Goes Here        Hospital Appointment
KEVIN MARTIN            UGT001    2017-12-29    08:14:13     17:14:13    No Comment
```

Just look at the UGT003 (this user can perform multiple check-ins and outs / shift schedule) from the result above, it were repeated due for reading both different check in time/comment and check out time/comment.

Is anybody can help solve this problem for my attendance system? Thank you.

Comment: use distinct...

Comment: Just run your code one query first then add the another subquery to check where is the issue occurs.

Comment: Still struggling? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You must aggregate your result. I have a doubt using distinct will give you the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are joining check-ins and check-outs only using `date` which is not enough to match them if there are multiple of them during one day. It matches every `in` with every `out` for this day which causes duplicates (and even multiplication when more cases are added to the same date).

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    b.name AS Name, 
    c.user_id AS User_ID , 
    c.date AS Date, 
    a.time As "Time In",
    c.time As "Time Out",
    a.comment AS "Comment In",
    c.comment AS "Comment Out"
FROM 
tbl_checkin a
LEFT JOIN tbl_checkout c ON c.date=a.date AND c.user_id=a.user_id AND c.Time >= a.Time
LEFT JOIN tbl_checkout co2 ON co2.user_id=c.user_id AND c.date=co2.date  AND co2.Time >= a.Time AND co2.Time < c.Time
INNER JOIN tbl_userlogin b ON c.user_id=b.user_id 


WHERE 
    co2.ID IS NULL

ORDER BY c.date DESC, a.Time, c.Time
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Now I have to check whether it fully work or not in the actual attendance system.